# size of iPad pro launch image 2x?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

I have search many sites and many posts but could not find information.Can anyone tell me size of pixel for launch image for iPad pro 12" inches.Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are no longer support launch images and will not be adding the iPad pro launch image size to asset catalogs.

You should use [Launch Screen Files](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/ConfiguringYourApp/ConfiguringYourApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH28-SW4) for iPad Pro instead of Launch Images. First, from iPad Pro, iOS don't support Launch Images, so you can not find the right sizes for iPad Pro's launch images in Xcode 7.1 and leter. Second, if you don't use Launch Screen File, you app running on iPad Pro will be scaled, which is so called 'Display Zoom'.

Answer (score 2):

1x will be 1366x 1024 in portrait
2x will be 2732x2048 in portrait

Answer (score 0):

It's the same size as the screen resolution.

> 2732-by-2048 resolution at 264 pixels per inch (ppi)

[As per Apple's website](http://www.apple.com/ipad-pro/specs/)